# Python: how to dynamically add a number to the end of the name of a list

Tags: python, list, dynamic, append, element

In python I am appending elements to a list. The element name I am getting from an input file, so the element_name is an unknown. I would like to create a new list by adding a number to the end of the original list (dyn_list1) or even by using one of the elements in the list (element_name). How can this be achieved?

```
dyn_list = []
for i in range(4):
    dyn_list.append(element_name)
```

I thought it would look something like:

```
dyn_list = []
for i in range(4):
     dyn_list%i.append(element_name)
 print(dyn_list)
```

But that obviously doesn't work.

To try to be clearer, what I am ultimately trying to do is create a dynamically named list, with a list name that I didn't have to explicitly define in advance.

**Update:**
This is not perfect, but it gets close to accomplishing what I want it to:

```
            for i in range(4):
                dyn_list.append(element_name)
                globals()[f"dyn_list{i}"] = dyn_list
            print("dyn_list %s" %dyn_list)
            print("Dyn_list1 %s" %dyn_list1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_list = ["something"]

g = globals()
for i in range(1, 5):
         g['dynamiclist_{0}'.format(i)] = my_list

print(dynamiclist_1)
print(dynamiclist_2)
print(dynamiclist_3)
print(dynamiclist_4)
```

> something like that ?

Comment: This is it. Thanks. Now can I call one of those dynamic list iterations? For example to print `print(dynamiclist_{i})`

Comment: Nevermind, this works: `print(f"dynamiclist_{i}")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but I think you want to add the data you get by reading a txt file or something like that at the end of your list. I'm answering this assuming. I hope it helps.

```
list_ = ["ethereum", "is", "future"]  #your list
new_list = []                         #declare your new list
list_len = len(list_)                 #get list len
with open('dynamic.txt') as f:        #read your file for dynamic string

    lines = f.readlines()


while list_len:   # so that the dynamic data does not exceed the length of the list

    for i in range(list_len):
        new_element = list_[i] + "." + str(lines[i])
        new_list.append(new_element)
        list_len -= 1  #Decrease to finish the while loop

for p in new_list: print(p)
```

Comment: Actually, I am trying to name a new list dynamically. So instead of new_list, it would be new_list1 or something like that, some name that I didn't have to explicitly define in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74321676/20408740

I think you are looking for something like this can you check my next answer?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a dictionary instead of a list. You could use something like

```
dyn_list = {}
for i in range(4) : 
    element_name = ...#some code to get element_name
    dyn_list[i] = element_name
```

Then if you want to retrieve the `i`th element, you can use

`dyn_list[i]`

Comment: I am actually trying to dynamically create a new list name. This just populates the already existing list name.